# calling a returned array value from class method - is it possible? - is it normal practice? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, oop, methods, return

is it possible to directly call the value returned from a method array?
for example

```
<?php
class test
{
    public function echo_test()
    {
        $return_value["a1"] = "a1a1";
        $return_value["b1"] = "b1b1";
        return $return_value;
    }
}

$newObj = new test();
echo $newObj->echo_test()['a1'];  //<----- this does not seem to work
echo $newObj->echo_test()->a1; //<--------- this does not seem to work as well
echo $newObj['a1']->echo_test(); //<--------- this also do not work

?>
```

Comment: The first one [*does* work](https://eval.in/46978), it's called array dereferencing and is only supported in PHP 5.4+ AFAIK. I think you should enable error reporting and start following some basic tutorials or read a book.

Comment: thanks, currently using netbeans and its showing error under the IDE before uploading to the server.   the reason is probably because the PHP server is running 5.3.   thanks for the clarification and the suggestion

Comment: The third way does not even make sense, since you are not returning an object, but a string.